# unauthorized access on artifactory even though credentials are included

Tags: maven, hudson, artifactory

I am trying to deploy a zip file to a remote inhouse maven repo.(artifactory integrated into hudson).

**pom.xml**

```
...
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>mygroupId</groupId>
<artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>   

<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>hudson</id>
      <name>hudson-releases</name>
      <url>http://url to repo</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
...
```

**settings.xml**

```
<servers>
<server>
  <id>hudson</id>
  <username>username</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
</servers>
```

**maven deploy**

```
 mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://url -Dfile=file-1.0.0.zip  -Dpackaging=zip  -DpomFile=pom.xml
```

maven quits with return code 401.

Looking at **artifactory's logs**

```
 2011-07-15 13:52:50,090 [DENIED DEPLOY] libs-release-local:somefile.zip for anonymous/192.168.220.146.
```

I don't understand why maven doesn't use the supplied credentials.
What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Actually I would thank you for post itself - it helped me to solve another problem. For some reason `artifactory-maven-plugin` did not send credentials from `publisher` configuration. I've added credentials into `server` block in settings.xml and it did it's job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason using a POM file didn't work. So i had to do it from command line.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://url -Dfile=file-1.0.0.zip  -Dpackaging=zip  -DartifactId=aid -DgroupId=groupId -DrepositoryId=repId -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I still do not know why this worked. Also , i didn't have to change settings.xml from what i listed before.

**EDIT**

Also, on the home tab in artifactory, you can get maven settings by clicking "Maven settings->Generate Settings" .

Comment: i have generated settings.xml from artifactory, and the user has deploy,read permission on that repository, but still i get the same error. "couldnot transfer artifact from/to central http:url..Access denied to url/name.jar.. reasonphrase:forbidden"
If i try to generate settings.xml by using admin credentials then it is able to download artifacts.
 May i know what is the exact reason for this?

Comment: Did you provide all the parameters provided in the answer ? Does repId exist in settings.xml ? and does the user have permissions to that repository ?

Answer (score 16):

Tip to solve the problem with the clear text password:

- Access and login into Artifactory.
- Once you are logged in, click over your user name, on the superior right corner of the screen.
- Put your password then clique in the em Unlockbutton, enabling the encrypted password.
- Copy the  tag that will be showed on the inferior part of the screen and paste it into the settings.xml file. If you prefer to just copy the password, be sure about let it exactly equals the  tag showed below, including the "\" at the beginning of the password.
- Remember to adjust the  tag with the id of your server, defined into the  tag, in your POM.xml
- Click in  Update  button and ready! Check if everything will occur well at the next project's publication.

Answer (score 4):

Don´t forget to check that what you put on `<distributionManagement>` at your **pom.xml** corresponds to what is on the tags of your **.m2/settings.xml.**

Answer (score 3):

Hudson is most likely caching settings.xml. You can try to reload configuration from the disk using this url http://your-hudson-url:8081/hudson/reload or restart the container Hudson is running on. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is not set to use preemptive authentication by default and has some issues when being challenged.

You can try configuring Maven's HttpClient Wagon to do preemptive authentication (http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html), though I rarely managed to get it working properly.
Since you're using Jenkins\Hudson, you might want to take a look at the Jenkins\Hudson - Artifactory plugin:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin
- http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Artifactory+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

You're publishing a snapshot version but you haven't specified a *snapshotRepository* tag in the  *distributionManagement* section of your POM. Alternatively try and deploy a normal version and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Update Maven configuration details and add the credentials of nexus:

```
credentials: admin
```